# How to get pair from a map using key in C++

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, std-pair

I have the following map:

```
std::map<char, std::pair<int, int> > robots;
```

I am using this function to populate the map given the input meets certain conditions:

```
bool World::addRobot(int row, int col, char robot_name) {

    // This if block checks if the desired location is a valid 1 and keeps a track of all the robots already in the grid
    if (map_[row][col] == '1' && robots.find(robot_name) == robots.end()){
        map_[row][col] = robot_name;
        robots.insert(make_pair(robot_name, std::make_pair(row, col)));
    }
    else{std::cout << "Invalid input" << std::endl;}

  return true;
}
```

Each robot name, which is just a single char, is saved with a pair of its location, which are just row/col coordinates. In the following function, I want to be able to retrieve & ethe location pairs given the robot name:

```
std::pair<int, int> World::getRobot(char robot_name) {

    std::pair<int, int> location = robots.find(robot_name);
    return location;
}
```

But the name `location` is redlines with the following error message:

```
No viable conversion from 'std::map<char, std::pair<int, int>>::iterator' (aka '_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const char, std::pair<int, int>>>') to 'std::pair<int, int>'
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I return the coordinate pairs from just the robot name?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Comment: why don't you just `return robots[robot_name];`. If there is a case which `robot_name` not exist in `robots`, you may need to handle that case too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An iterator for a map "points to" a `std::pair<const KEY, VALUE>`.

For your map, the `KEY` is `char` and the `VALUE` is `std::pair<int, int>`

So in your code, instead of:

```cpp
std::pair<int, int> location = robots.find(robot_name);
```

you need to:

```cpp
std::pair<int, int> location = robots.find(robot_name)->second;
```

Also, you need to check and see if the call to find fails to find the key you want. In that case the iterator will be equal to `robots.end`, and you'll have to deal with that:

```cpp
const auto it = robots.find(robot_name);
if (it != robots.end()) {
    return it->second;
} else {
    // Not found, do something else
}
```

Comment: The error is when `location` is declared, not returned..

Answer (score 2):

[`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) returns a map iterator which is a "logical pointer" to a [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) of **key** and **value** of the element in the map (not only the value).
The `second` member of this pair is the **value** that you seek to return from `getRobot` (which is by itself a pair of `int`s).

Fixed version:

```
std::pair<int, int> World::getRobot(char robot_name) 
{
    auto it = robots.find(robot_name);
    if (it == robots.end())
    {
        return std::pair<int, int>(0, 0);   // return some default value
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

2 additional notes:

1. I used `auto`  which is very convenient when using iterators (instead of specifying the long iterator type).
2. I added a check whether the key is in the map. If not - return some default value. You can change the default value, or change the method prototype to return an error status in this case.

Comment: What if I want to return the `robot_name` and the location pairs together? Like this: `(robot_name, (row, col))`?

Comment: You can return `std::pair<char, std::pair<int,int>>(robot_name, it->second)` (you'll also need to change the method's return type accordingly).

Comment: @oo92 BTW - note that I changed the initialization of `it`. There's actually no need to use `&` for an iterator.